# Single ajax post to WCF service invokes service method multiple times

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf

I am trying to upload a file to a WCF service. This is my ajax post.

```
 $.ajax({
     cache: false,
     url: "MyService.svc/UploadFile",
     type: "POST",
     data: document.getElementById("fileUpload1").files[0],
     processData: false
 });
```

Element with ID fileUpload1 is just an ordinary element of type "input".

This is my WCF operation.

Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
ScriptResult UploadFile(Stream stream);
```

Implementation:

```
    public ScriptResult UploadFile(Stream stream) {
        try {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            stream.CopyTo(ms);

            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Folder1\somefilename.someExtension", ms.ToArray());

            return Result("OK");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.Error(e);

            return Error(e);
        }
    }
```

The solution above works fine, except for 2 things:

1. The UploadFile-method gets called more than once, meaning that the file gets overwritten X times. The last version of the file to be saved is perfectly valid (as long as I manually change the extension of the file to actual file type). How many times the method gets called depends on which file I choose to upload. Perhaps it's got something to do with the size of the file - perhaps not. I haven't been able to find any pattern in this behavior, but all invocations definitely contains a full and valid Stream.

   2. In Chrome, the ajax-call fails with error "net::ERR_INVALID_HANDLE"  ....even though, UploadFile is invoked X times - every time with valid data in the stream-object.

Anyone have an idea of why this is working like this? It makes no sense to me. I tried decoration the interface-method in varies ways with the WebInvoke-attribute like described many places on Google and setting the content-type in the ajax-call to json, xml and whatnot, but the only combination that makes it all the way to the service-method is leaving content-type unspecified (or set to "false").

I tried this: [WCF service multiple method calls one ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878739/wcf-service-multiple-method-calls-one-ajax-request) with no luck.

I considered if it's got something to do with the way I process the stream after the method is invoked (like if you don't read ALL the data from the stream, then WCF might "offer" it again to the method as an n'th chance to empty it completely, but it's a long shot and didn't work).

Any ideas at all? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "The UploadFile-method gets called more than once..." Why? What's calling it?

Comment: I'm calling it ..once ..using the ajax-call shown above. I used the debugging tools in Chrome, to verify that I truly make only a single call, but even so, the Upload-file is invoked several times (presumable by some kind of WCF-logic behind the scenes).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly implementation of sevices you can test on tools like SOAP UI or Postman that have properties to called only once when you called other than you test with browser that's own property to calling method n no of time upto still get any response.

So you can use tool then implement.

I faced these issue much times.